# Can I move a certificate purchased in one Azure subscription to another Azure subscription later?

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate, azure-web-app-service

I am thinking of buying a wildcard certificate for my domain. In the near future, we plan to move the app and app service and databases to another Azure subscription. I would like to know if it is possible to move the wildcard certificate to the new subscription?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, it should be able to meet your requirements, but there are some things that need attention. [Move guidance for App Service resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-limitations/app-service-move-limitations)

You need to try,if can't. You will need to delete the SSL bindings, and move a certificate bound to the new website.